# Calculate $\int_\phi \omega$, where: $\phi(t)$ and $\omega$ are specified.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Calculate $\int_\phi \omega$, where:

$\phi(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$

$\phi(t) = \Big( 2 + 16t^2(t-1)^2, 4t(1-t), (1-t) \big( 1 + 16t^2(t-1)(2t-1) \big)  \Big)$

$\omega = \big( 2xz^2 e^{x^2 + y^2} + 2xz \big)dx + \big( 2yz^2 e^{x^2 + y^2} + 2yz \big)dy + \big( 2z e^{x^2 + y^2} + x^2 + y^2 \big)dz$

For: $F(x, y, z) = z^2 e^{x^2 + y^2} + z(x^2 + y^2)$ we have that: $\omega = dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} dz$

Therefore, from Gradient theorem: $\int_\phi \omega = \int_\phi \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} dz = \int_0^1 \Big( \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dt} \Big) dt = F(\phi(1)) - F(\phi(0))$

$\phi(0) = (2, 0, 1)$ and $\phi(1) = (2, 0, 0)$

From that:
$$\int_\phi \omega = z^2 e^{x^2 + y^2} + z(x^2 + y^2)  = 0 - (e^4 + 4) = -e^4 - 4$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Set $F(x,y,z)=z^2e^{x^2+y^2}+z(x^2+y^2)$  and notice that $\omega=dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} dz$.

Comment: See: [Gradient theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think I get it now. Thank you for help. I will edit my original post to evaluate if my understanding is correct :)

Comment: @StinkingBishop is that correct now?

Comment: From a glance, it looks correct. I am not sure whether it is ok to change the question into a completely different question, but the way it is now, I will add solution-verification tag so that others can chip in.